# Putting both Lambda and RDS in default VPC behind an API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to have an architecture with:

Route53 <-> API gateway <-> Lambda <-> RDS and DynamoDB.

I am confused about some networking aspects here!

From most of the documentation, what I understand is that Lambda is by default launched in default VPC and can access internet from there but no resources inside a "VPC". And this 2nd VPC (in quotes) refers to non-default VPCs in most discussions. But what is not clear is what if I placed the Lambda and RDS both in default VPC, lambda in a public subnet with --vpc-config info and RDS in a private subnet, will my Lambda have the internet connection?

Even when everything is in default subnet, should I put my lambda function in to a private subnet with Internet access through an Amazon VPC NAT gateway?

I know it is a theoretical question - documents are confusing me by not explicitly mentioning what cannot be done!

Answer (score 5):

> From most of the documentation, what I understand is that Lambda is by
>   default launched in default VPC and can access internet from there but
>   no resources inside a "VPC".

That is incorrect. By default Lambda is not launched in a VPC at all. Or if it is in a VPC it is in one that you cannot see because it doesn't exist in your AWS account.

> what if I placed the Lambda and RDS both in default VPC, lambda in a
>   public subnet with --vpc-config info and RDS in a private subnet, will
>   my Lambda have the internet connection?

No, your Lambda function will not have internet access, even in a public subnet. This is because it is never assigned a public IP address. Once you place a Lambda function inside a VPC you have to have a NAT gateway in order to for the Lambda function to access anything outside the VPC.

> Even when everything is in default subnet, should I put my lambda
>   function in to a private subnet with Internet access through an Amazon
>   VPC NAT gateway?

Yes, that is the correct way to provide a Lambda function with access to both a VPC and resources that exist outside the VPC.

---

Also note that DynamoDB (and the AWS API) does not run in your VPC. So if you place a Lambda function inside your VPC that needs to access DynamoDB, or anything else that is accessed via the AWS API, you will have to add a NAT gateway to the VPC.

---

Note that the "Default VPC" is the term for a  the VPC that is setup for you when you first create your AWS account. You can see this VPC in your account in the VPC service console. Aside from it being created for you with default settings, you should just think of this as another VPC in your account. The Default VPC is not used by Lambda when you don't specify a VPC, and it is not used by other services like DynamoDB that exist outside your VPC network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It was a good sounding board for me! But then brings more questions. With NAT how does the routing work?

1. Typically NAT will only route outgoing traffic to the internet and not allow incoming traffic. What happens to incoming REST calls from the API Gateway.

2. API Gateway will route different REST methods to the same internet gateway to the same NAT and then to different lambda functions each of which could be accessing a different vpc or non-vpc resource. Too much configuration of security groups, routing tables, etc. in the lambda subnets? Any example?

Comment: I believe you are over thinking this. The NAT gateway would only be used for outbound traffic from the private subnets in your VPC. The way API Gateway to Lambda communication works will not change due to the absence or presence of a NAT gateway. Also note that API Gateway exists outside your VPC, and invokes your Lambda functions directly via the AWS API.